# Get a file path in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use the image `smile.jpg`. I've saved the **jpg** file into location **../project/Cam/bin/Debug/smile.jpg**    (this part of path is static)

But the previous path is dynamic, can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: you could at least show the effort you did already.

Comment: You have literally answered 95% of your own question just by asking it..

Comment: From your question I would like to mention `God Helps Those Who Help Themselves`.. What are you asking it is not clear..

Comment: Do not hardcode any paths - ever! Period! `/project/Cam/...` may exist on your development machine, but will it also exist on the user's machine?

Comment: Sorry .. in my development machine the jpg is saved in pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/12345678/project/Cam/bin/Debug/smile.jpg");  but when I run the program in other machine.. the path is xxxxx/project/Cam/bin/Debug/smile.jpg")  and i have tried to type ("../project/Cam/bin/Debug/smile.jpg")  the file still cannot be found

Comment: And on another machine (after installing the application using a setup) there won't be a "project/Cam/bin/Debug" folder at all - imagine that! Add the image to resources or load them from the Assembly folder as suggested in the answers.

Comment: to thorsten..thx for your suggestion..you are right..so i am finding the way to get dynamic path

Comment: I'll write an answer to show you different solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Not very clear  which path is which, but try to "play" with

[Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) and [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

```
//THIS RETURNS YOU A FOLDER WHERE YOUR APPLICATION RUNS
var exeutingFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

and

```
//COMBINE EXECUTING FOLDER WITH RELATIVE PATH YOU HAVE
var resultinPath = Path.Combine(executingFolder, YOUR_PATH);
```

Comment: Thx let me hv a try :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions to the underlying problem of loading an image that is shipped with the application:

**Solution 1: Resources**
If it is not necessary that the image file is present, you can simply add the image to your program's resources and assign it in the designer. The image file then doesn't have to be deployed.

To do so, add the image file to your project, then, drag it to the "Resources" tab of your projects properties.

**Solution 2: Files copied to the output folder**
Maybe you want your images in your output folder and load them from files at runtime. Then you should *really avoid* making any assumptions about the folder, but instead do the following:

1. Add the image files to your project and set their built type to "none" and have them be always copied to the output folder. If you build your project, the image files should now be in `/bin/debug` or `/bin/release`.
2. In your code, build a path to the files using the assembly folder

This code gets the assembly folder and assembles a path name to an image named "smiley.png":

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string smileyPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "smiley.png");
```

In case you added the images to a folder within your project, the folder will also be created in the output folder. For example: if you put your images into a folder "images", there will be a folder "images" in `bin/debug` or `bin/release`. In that case you can safely make the assumption that the following code will work:

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string imagePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "images");
string smileyPath = Path.Combine(imagePath, "smiley.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the full path from the relative path?

If so, you can use [System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

e.g.

`string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../project/Cam/bin/Debug/smile.jpg");`